# Formatting number from the hit counter (how to add comma)

Tags: number-format

I need to display the number of visitors to a website on the homepage, and I'm wondering if there is a way to add formmating to the number output by the {hits} variable.  http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/hit_counter.html

I've tried a few plugins, like "number-formatter" and even the "price-format" but I think the issue is that the {hits} won't parse from within some of these plugin tags.

Is there a better way to display (and format) the total number of visits to any one page on a site with EE?

THANKS!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to parse order. {hits} isn't tag specific, so probably gets parsed later than the plugins you're using to format the value.

Try using [track_views="one" parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-entries-track-views) on the channel:entries tag you use to build the homepage (assuming you have an entry associated with the homepage), that will give you the equivalent of {hits}. Then use {view_count_one} in the template, which should get parsed prior to the plugin that formats it: [Number formatter](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/number-formatter), [Number Format](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/number-format), etc.